i have problem to use robot_localization packages
This error appeared when I used the robot_localization package, possibly because I used the diff_tf package as the odomwheel topic.

When the error above appears, my robot on rviz looks like a glitch

and this my ekf.yaml
frequency: 30  # Frekuensi estimasi (Hz)
sensor_timeout: 0.1  # Timeout (detik) untuk setiap sensor
two_d_mode: false  # Mode dua dimensi (true/false)

transform_time_offset: 0.0  # Waktu offset transform (detik)
transform_timeout: 0.0  # Timeout untuk transform (detik)

odom_frame: odom  # Nama frame odom
base_link_frame: base_link  # Nama frame base_link

world_frame: odom  # Nama frame world
map_frame: map  # Nama frame map



odom0: /odomwheel  # Topik odometri
odom0_config: [false,  false, false,
               false, false,  true,
               false,  false, false,
               false, false,  true,
               false, false, false]  # Konfigurasi odometri (position, linear velocity)
odom0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true

        #        [x_pos   , y_pos    , z_pos,
        #         roll    , pitch    , yaw,
        #         x_vel   , y_vel    , z_vel,
        #         roll_vel, pitch_vel, yaw_vel,
        #         x_accel , y_accel  , z_accel]


imu0: /imu/data  # Topik IMU
imu0_config: [false, false, false,
              false, false, true,
              false, false, false,
              false, false, true,
              false, false, false]
 # Konfigurasi IMU (orientation, angular velocity, linear acceleration)
imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true
imu0_rejection_treshold: 3
```


The error tells itself. You are publishing two tfs from odom to baselink at the same time and it causes the glitch. You have to set publish_tf to false in one the packages so there is only one transformation from odom to baselink.

so, if I want to use a wheel encoder for robot localization, how do I send the required data to the robot_localization package?

Your question is a little bit ambiguous for me. Do you mean that you have the /odom topic and don't know what to do with it or you want to know how to produce odometry data from wheel encoders? I assume that your problem is the latter. In that case you can you this link to produce odometry topic from wheel encoders: https://automaticaddison.com/how-to-publish-wheel-odometry-information-over-ros/ .
